# Solarized color scheme and palette distorts for ssh'd users in iTerm2

Tags: vim, color-scheme, tmux, iterm, ansi-term

My setup includes vim, iTerm2, tmux, and the solarized dark color scheme.  I have the dark solarized color palette loaded into iTerm2 (modifies the ansi colors) and do not use the degraded solarized color scheme (i.e., `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`) as talked about in the readme as an alternative to using the color palette.  Everything looks great.

But, I often remote pair with co-workers.  Folks ssh into my machine from other instances of iTerm2 and sometimes Terminal.app and create a new tmux session with my tmux session as their base/parent session.  In the case of iTerm2, their setup does not include loading the solarized color palette (one uses another palette entirely) and setting the `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` to use the degraded solarized color scheme.  If that's what they want, great, but when they connect to me via ssh/tmux the colors are lost and often times distorted to the point of being illegible.

Is there any combination of settings, besides having everyone use the same settings, to remedy this?  Right now the recommendation is for me to use the degraded color scheme and not load the solarized color palette so that the ansi colors are not modified.  This does work, but leaves me w/ the degraded solarized color scheme.  And as I prefer the non-degraded solarized color scheme, I'd prefer not to take this approach.

Answer (score 1):

When used in a terminal, the solarized colorscheme for Vim defaults to 16 colors and depends on the palette of the terminal emulator because it uses "Red", "Yellow"… as values for `ctermfg` and friends.

If you want the same colors everywhere you obviously need to have the same palette everywhere because your "Red" may not be someone else's "Red".

I don't know what the author smoked when he wrote it but `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` is not "degraded" *at all* compared to the default. The default uses only a palette of 16 colors (dependant on the terminal's palette, as we have already seen) while this option makes it use a terminal-independant 256 colors palette. Because the colorscheme is not dependant on the terminal emulator's palette anymore, the colors are actually "guaranteed" to look "good" and "the same" on your terminal emulator and on someone else's terminal emulator.

The catch is that your terminal emulator and their terminal emulators must support 256 colors. All of todays terminals do, but the default is often set to 16 colors. It's generally easy to turn 256 colors support "on", though.

But this option is Vim-only. The colors of your prompt or of the output of some commands or of `tmux`'s TUI *may* still feel "off" to your co-workers.

The ability to customize the hell out of your setup is of course an important aspect of the Vim experience. But customization comes at a price. You get used to many little things and it could happen that, confronted to a vastly different setup, well… you just get lost. Or, as happens to you, your setup is customized to the point of being unusable by your co-workers.

Pair programming can *only* work if you and your pair are able to reach compromise on a setup. Obviously, this setup may not be exactly *yours* or *his* but you *must* find a middle ground on which everyone agrees for pairing to work. Because you and your pair may use different versions of tmux/vim, different shells or different terminal emulators, the safest bet is to use the most basic setup possible. Unfortunately for you, solarized is too fragile and far from being "basic" enough.